Converting pyarrow Table to RecordBatches of a fixed byte size
I appreciate this might be impossible in the most general, case but is there a way to convert a pyarrow table into record batches of a fixed maximum byte size? I know I can request a maximum row size, so this should be possible if I can find the maximum row size for a given schema. I didn't see anything in the docs of either pa.Schema or pa.Field about their sizes?

I just found sum(t.bit_width for t in schema.types) which will raise an exception if there are non-fixed-width types (e.g. strings) in the schema, but otherwise do the right thing

Though I imagine nullable columns have to be considered here, too. I have now gone with taking table.nbytes / table.shape[0] which should give the right answer for fixed size data, and an average number for variable size data.
